# Two URLs with same structure

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How to make two URLs with same structure make work?
I don't want to add any prefix before the URL. I want all views to be `example.com/[slug]`.

Here are my URLs:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)', views.CategoryArticlesView.as_view(), name='single_category'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)', views.SingleArticleView.as_view(), name='single_article'),
```

I can easily make it work by adding a prefix before first URL like:

```
url(r'^**category/**(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)', views.CategoryArticlesView.as_view(), name='single_category'),
```

but I want it without prefix.
Now it matches only first URL but not the second.

Comment: You can do it, checking matching category or article directly in your view, and then calling corresponding action. But this approach considered to be a very bad practice, as it's completely eliminates the benefits of Django routing system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do what you want that way. Instead, you may add another view where you can dispatch your requests based on some condition like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    if some_condition:
        return CategoryArticlesView.as_view()(self.request)
    else:
        return SingleArticleView.as_view()(self.request)
```

Now, your url config can be:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)', views.some_view, name='some_name'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create two urls with the same pattern car Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL. see [how-django-processes-a-request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)